# export server for highcharts

Tags: highcharts

This is related to the new feature launched in Highcharts - exporting server working with PhantomJS

http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-news/52-serverside-generated-charts

Is there any comparison in terms of performance with Highcharts Serverside Export done by one2team versus this newly released export server? Also under higher volumes, is spawning a new thread from Java and initiating a new PhantomJS process stable? Could you please share
statistics on peak volume, concurrent users tested, response time with server configurations?

Regards
Ramkumar

Answer (score 0):

The export server solution of One2Team uses [Rhino](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rhino) under the hood and it seems that Rhino is not always returning a precise bounding box of SVG elements. For building the layout in Highcharts the bounding box is used for calculating margins. With a incorrect size for the boudingbox, it can result in for example overlapping labels.

From my experience at Highcharts, the provided Java/PhantomJS solution is very stable. It's running stable for almost two months. We haven't done benchmarks, but in average we get 6 visits per minute per day.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. On the issues related to bounding box you had mentioned could you please post an example where running it with One2Team's solution, the labels overlap. Is there any specific pattern in which it could happen?

Comment: Based on our initial analysis we find invoking the PhantomJS as a separate process is slower against HSE for both Pie charts and Bar charts we tested. We found that PhantomJS has a built-in webserver feature - Mongoose - http://ariya.ofilabs.com/2012/01/glory-of-the-snow.html which helps make process communication simpler (and also avoids the I/O in the infile, outfile approach). We could execute with that and found PhantomJS was equal or better than HSE in performance. But not sure yet on how much load it could take and respond in production traffic. Have you evaluated any such options?

Comment: could you please answer on the comments? If you would want it to be posed a new question, please let know as  well.

Comment: answered on your comments, here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14937651/highcharts-phantomjs-alternative-approach/15244482#15244482 and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14937724/highcharts-boundingbox-issue-with-env-js/15243743#15243743